# While creating dummy variables getting memory error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am working on a project and While getting the dummies value i was getting memory exception

I have tried using `.astype(np.int8)` and i have also tried writing exception handling code by importing `psutil`

i am using below code

```
dummy_cols = ['emp_title','grade','home_ownership','verification_status','addr_state','pub_rec','application_type']
df_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df[dummy_cols], drop_first = True)
```

It's not working and throwing an error

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.get_dummies` creates a dense representation of dummy variables, which may request lots of memory depending on the number of levels in the categorical features.

I would prefer `scikit-learn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder` that outputs sparse matrices:

The code would look like this :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

# Create a fake dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "df1": np.random.choice(["a", "b"], 100),
        "df2": np.random.choice(["c", "d"], 100)
    }
)
dummy_cols = ["df1", "df2"]

# LabelEncode categoricals
for f in dummy_cols:
    df[f] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df[f])

# Transform to dummies in sparse representation (csr_matrix)
df_dummies = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(df[dummy_cols])
```

Comment: I tried this as well but it is not working any alternative way

Comment: @emipatha, do you still get a memory exception ?

Comment: I resolved by using find and replace and hot encoding